# For loop with if estatement

Tags: c++

How to convert this to for loop? Im doing it several times to convert it  but its hard to get the logic of it.

```
int total, gradecounter, grade;
double average;

total = 0;
gradecounter = 0;

cout<<"Enter grade, -1 to end";
cin>> grade;

while (grade != -1) {
    total = total + grade;
    gradecounter = gradecounter + 1;
    cout<<"Enter grade, -1 to end:";
    cin>>grade;
}

if (gradecounter =0) {
    average = total/gradecounter;
    cout<<"Class Average is "<<average<<endl;
    getche();
    return 0;
}

getche();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Why do you want to convert this to a `for` loop? It's not hard to do, but it definitely makes the code worse. Also, this program currently ignores the first grade entered and, which is presumably wrong.

Comment: because sir its my hobby to converted the while to for or for to while but this time im stuck at this code, its really hard to get the logic and yeah my head hurts for solving it thats why i need help to how get the logic and also to enhance my knowledge of C++. sorry by the way for asking question like this

Answer (score 0):

I won't post your code but you can find plenty of resources of how to convert a while loop to a for loop

The while

```
init;
while(condition)
  //body
  increment;
```

becomes

```
for(init; condition; increment) 
  //body
```

Comment: Hm, don't forget the actual loop body ;-)

Comment: @ThomasLang Ahh, thanks. I did the edit to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int total, gradecounter, grade;
    double average;

    total = 0;
    gradecounter = 0;

    cout<<"Enter grade, -1 to end";
    cin>> grade;

    // for (initial variable; loop condition of execuate; update Sentence)
    for (;grade != -1; cout<<"Enter grade, -1 to end:", cin>>grade) {
        total = total + grade;
        gradecounter = gradecounter + 1;
    }

    if (gradecounter !=0) 
    {
        average = total / gradecounter;
        cout<<"Class Average is "<<average<<endl;
        // getche();
        return 0;
    }
    // getche();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why is there a `cout` in the loop increment expression? What does that accomplish? Alternatively, why not put the whole loop body in there?

Comment: code only answers arent nice. Without explanation this is of limited use. Next time OP needs to transform a different while loop to a for loop, they will have to ask again